# Dacpac File and Deploying Data Tier Application Error

Tags: sql-server, data-tier-applications

[image]

I am using the new SQL Server tools with the data-tier project in Visual Studio. I created a snapshot (.dacpac) and I tried to deploy it on a SQL Server instance in management studio but I get the following error. Any clues?

My dacpac file and SQL Server are all local.

```
The stream cannot be read to construct the DacType. Unexpected XML content.
```

Comment: Which versions of VS and SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Did you create this data-tier application from a BACPAC file (i.e. export of a SQL Azure database as a BACPAC)?